# Apache Spark - How to design own aggregation with Window Operations on Event Time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to calculate the **ratio of supply and demand**. Data recode with time_to_pick_up,time_to_drop_off, pick_up_location,drop_off_location fields.

2019-01-01 00:22:21,2019-01-01 00:43:43,Union Sq,SoHo

I am going to split the record to two record so data will looks like below:

2019-01-01 00:22:21, Union Sq, PICK

2019-01-01 00:43:43, SoHo, DROP

2019-01-01 00:22:23, Union Sq, DROP

....

The ratio = (PICK+ DROP)/PICK = 2/1 = 2
(because DROP means the car is available so the supply count was added one.
; the record for PICK will contribute demand and supply at same time
) And I want to report the ratio **within one hour every 5 mins**

```
 val perMinCount = ds.filter(col("zone")== "Union Sq").withWatermark("datetime", "10 minutes")
    .groupBy($"zone",window($"datetime", "1 hours","5 minutes")).agg(?)
```

This is what I do so far. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem without writing custom aggregation also.
You can use when, otherwise with groupBy, agg to achieve this.
e.g.

```
//streaming df
+-------------------+--------+-----+
|datetime           |zone    |event|
+-------------------+--------+-----+
|2019-11-06 11:32:21|Union Sq|PICK |
|2019-11-06 11:32:22|SoHo    |DROP |
|2019-11-06 11:32:23|Union Sq|DROP |
+-------------------+--------+-----+

val enrichedStreamingDf = streamingDf
  .withColumn("demand",
    when(col("event") === "PICK", lit(1))
      .when(col("event") === "DROP", lit(0))
      .otherwise(lit(0)))
  .withColumn("supply",
    when(col("event") === "PICK", lit(1))
      .when(col("event") === "DROP", lit(1))
      .otherwise(lit(0)))
  .filter(col("zone") === "Union Sq")

//enriched streaming df
+-------------------+--------+-----+------+------+
|datetime           |zone    |event|demand|supply|
+-------------------+--------+-----+------+------+
|2019-11-06 11:32:21|Union Sq|PICK |1     |1     |
|2019-11-06 11:32:23|Union Sq|DROP |0     |1     |
+-------------------+--------+-----+------+------+

val ratioDf = enrichedStreamingDf
  .withWatermark("datetime", "10 minutes")
  .groupBy(
    window($"datetime", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),
    $"zone"
  )
  .agg((sum($"supply") / sum($"demand")).as("sup_dem_ratio"))

//supply to demand ratio streaming df
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|window                                    |zone    |sup_dem_ratio|
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|[2019-11-06 11:25:00, 2019-11-06 11:35:00]|Union Sq|2.0          |
|[2019-11-06 11:30:00, 2019-11-06 11:40:00]|Union Sq|2.0          |
+------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

In this example, I have taken total duration of window as "10 minutes", you can use "1 hour" for your case.